# How to align text on the left in the last column of a table?

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

Here is my code :

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{changepage}

\begin{table}[H]
\begin{adjustwidth}{-2.5cm}{-1.5cm}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2.25cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3.8cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{5.5cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3.5cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{2.5cm}|}
    \hline
    \textbf{A} & \textbf{B} & \textbf{C} & \textbf{D} & \textbf{E} \\ \hline
    blabla & \raggedright blabla & \raggedright blabla & \raggedright blabla & {\raggedright}test \\ \hline
    blabla & \raggedright blabla & \raggedright blabla & \raggedright blabla & {\raggedright}test \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{table}
```

The compilation works fine, but the content in the last column is not align on the left line, which I really want.

I read on the website it's something to do with `{\raggedright}` in the last cell. Despite my efforts, I didn't get it in the right way. Could someone please help me to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please
take the [tour](/tour), have a look around, and
read through the [help center](/help), in particular
[How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic). From that second link: "Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it." Your example does not compile. Please enhance it to a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{2.5cm}` ?

Comment: or (loading `ragged2e`), `>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}m{2.5cm}` if you want to allow some hyphenation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set your column specification to match the style that you'll have most of in your column, and change the respective cells that deviate from this using `\multicolumn`s or per-cell adjustments as needed.

To that end, the setup below sets each column to use a `\raggedright` alignment, but only adjusts the header row with `\centering`. It lightens the amount of code and makes things more clear in its presentation.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}% Just for this example
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}
  {| >{\raggedright}m{2.25cm}
   | >{\raggedright}m{3.8cm}
   | >{\raggedright}m{5.5cm}
   | >{\raggedright}m{3.5cm}
   | >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{2.5cm}|}
  \hline
  \centering\textbf{A} & \centering\textbf{B} & \centering\textbf{C} & \centering\textbf{D} & \centering\arraybackslash\textbf{E} \\
  \hline
  blabla & blabla & blabla & blabla & test \\
  \hline
  blabla & blabla & blabla & blabla & test \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quiet sure, what you want exactly and why you try to make it so complicated (from my point of view).

It seems to me, that you want to have 5 rows, with the first and last one aligned to the left, and the rest to be aligned to the right.

Why didn't you make the table as follows:

```
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{l r r r l}
bla & bla & bla & bla & blabla \\ \hline
this is left-aligned & this is right-aligned & this too & and so is this & left-aligned\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Where the parameters l and r (and c) define the alignment of the correspondig row:

c - centered

l - left

r - right

Answer (score 1):

let me elaborate my comment above. by help of `\thead{...}` from package `makecell` the solution is simple:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{array, makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{adjustwidth}{-2.5cm}{-1.5cm}
\centering
\begin{tabular}
  {| >{\raggedright}m{2.25cm}
   | >{\raggedright}m{3.8cm}
   | >{\raggedright}m{5.5cm}
   | >{\raggedright}m{3.5cm}
   | >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{2.5cm}|}
  \hline
  \thead{A} & \thead{B} & \thead{C} & \thead{D} & \thead{E} \\
  \hline
  blabla & blabla & blabla & blabla & test \\
  \hline
  blabla & blabla & blabla & blabla & test \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustwidth}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would like to thank all of you for your quick answers.

The solution of Michael Schmid was not tested, because the result won't be the one I expected, which was centering the content only in the first row and column, and align the rest to the left.

I personally tried the solution posted by Werner. Indeed, the solution was lighter than my previous code. It worked perfectly, thanks!

Because I'm in a hurry to finish my work I didn't try other solutions proposed.

I mark the problem as solved.

Best regards,

Xavier.